# замена слова в предложении

Tags: выбор-слов

С  наступающим вас новым годом!
Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли заменить без потери смысла одно слово в ниженаписанном предложении другим словом, которое выделено в скобках:
"он просто стоял себе под солнцем, наслаждаясь ветром, летящим в щели, если тот дул от леса, или впадая в легкую депрессию, если ветер (он) дул со стороны помойки."
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве варианта:

*...он просто стоял себе под солнцем, **наслаждаясь летящим в щели ветром, когда** тот дул от леса, или впадая в легкую депрессию, **если ветер был** со стороны помойки.*

Пояснение

Смысл при замене не потеряется, но стиль будет некорректным (это мы улавливаем подсознательно). Поэтому *ветер* можно повторить дважды, но при этом убрать другие повторы.